# Best practice for dynamic backend postgresql and static interface localization

Tags: postgresql, web, next.js, localization, i18next

I building a website with a **Postgresql** database and **Nextjs**. I should localize it, what I should do to localize the static interface and data from the database?
Can you provide me best variant to do this?

I tried to search how to localize **static interface** and for Nextjs I found **i18next** library.
Is it correct to localize the static interface with this library?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.